# Plotting .asc with right geographic coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial, gdal, shapefile

I am trying to plot some map data, which I have access to as 'ASCII Grid and GML'.

I'd like to plot the map data against latitude and longitude on the x/y axis. However, the 'default' are some values that I don't quite understand.

Code below:

```
# join ASCII tiles together to get area of interest
tile_list = glob.glob("data/01/input/OS/NY/NY[0-9][0-9].asc")
vrt = gdal.BuildVRT("merged.vrt", tile_list)
gdal.Translate("mergeDEMvrt.tif", vrt)
vrt = None

grid = Grid.from_raster('mergeDEMvrt.tif', data_name='dem')
dem = grid.read_raster('mergeDEMvrt.tif')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10))
fig.patch.set_alpha(0)

plt.imshow(dem, extent=grid.extent, cmap='terrain', zorder=1)
plt.colorbar(label='Elevation (m)')
plt.grid(zorder=0)
plt.title('Digital elevation map', size=14)
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Tif to large to upload - Ref Image with wrong Axis]
The above image show the plot with the 'wrong' axis format. I would need the ususal long/lat values.

Do I need to overlay another layer when merging the individual tiles? I have tried another .tif file and the geo coordinates pulled through perfectly fine.

Also have access to the files as shapefile, but encountered the same problem. Other available file types are GML, GeoPackage or Vector Tiles.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: looks like you may have grid information in Eastings and Northings. Without more details from the files you are using to generate this plot, it's hard to say

Comment: I would guess you have epsg:27700 or OSGB data (based on the file names) so you could reproject to epsg:4326 or WGS84 for lat lon

Comment: A few quick tips: First, when creating temporary files, use `/vsimem/` file names which remain in memory. Then, the axes problem - there are two possible explanations - either your ASC files come with `.aux.xml` sidecar files - since ASC files do not specify axes - or this is simply the default axes arrangement of `matplotlib` which I haven't used. Check for `aux.xml` files and if you don't have them invert the axes in `matplotlib`.

Comment: Well spotted, @IanTurton 
It is, indeed, the OS Terrain50. Thanks for the information, I was unaware of that! Having looked into this a little, I think I might in fact reproject the coordinates of my POIs into OSGB, rather than the entire coordinate system to WGS84.

Comment: Thanks @mmomtchev 
What is the working difference between 'vsimem' and 'vrt'?
Also, my files do come with 'aux.xml' files, as you suggested. How would I ensure that I carry that information forwards when tiling lots of them together?

Comment: The `vsimem` refers to an in-memory file location, compared to on-disk. You can also use Cartopy, specify the correct projection for the axes, that allows keeping your data as it is (avoiding a reprojection etc). That way you can automatically show the gridlines/labels in lat/lon (can of course also be done manually).